# A variant of travel salesman problem with charging points

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms, approximation-algorithms, traveling-salesman-problem

Given a graph composed of a set $V$ of nodes, each representing a point to be visited by a salesman, and a set of fixed charging points. The salesman disposes a car that can travel $D$ distance before charging. We seek a minimal length path for the salesman to visit all the vertices in $V$. The distance between any pair of vertices is given. The problem differs from the standard TSP as the salesman may need to pass the charging point for replenishment.

Comment: Sounds a little like The Jeep Problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeep_problem

Comment: Thank you for the comment. It is somewhat different as we need to pass all the vertices in a graph.

Comment: What kind of answer would satisfy you? The standard exponential algorithms for TSP (e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Held%E2%80%93Karp_algorithm) seem like they would apply here also, and it would be unreasonable to expect any improvement on them here.

Comment: TSP has good approximation algorithms. I wonder if we can also design approximation algorithms for my probem.